# What calendar is Mathematica using for dates in the distant past?

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, version-8, implementation-details

It appears that *Mathematica* treats all dates as [proleptic Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) dates by default, a hypothesis that can be easily tested by using `AbsoluteTime` to [compute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11237/37) the [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day):

```
jd[t_] := AbsoluteTime[t]/86400 + 2.4150205*^6
```

but, while this works for recent dates and for some older ones, it yields results that differ from the [correct result](http://www.celnav.de/longterm.htm) for some older dates by exactly a day

```
jd[{2012, 11, 24, 12}] - 2456256
0
jd[{1100, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}] - 2123154
0
jd[{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}] - 625660
1
```

notably for the reference date, 12:00 Universal Time on January 1, 4713 BCE in the proleptic Julian calendar (-4713-11-24 in the proleptic Gregorian calendar):

```
jd[{-4713, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
1
```

What calendar is *Mathematica* using for these older dates, if not the proleptic Gregorian calendar?

Here, perhaps is another clue:

```
DateList[{-4713, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
{-4713, 11, 25, 12, 0, 0}
DateList[{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
{-3000, 11, 25, 12, 0, 0}
```

I'm no calendar expert, but this "canonicalization" doesn't map to any calendar I'm familiar with. Is this a bug?

---

*Update*: Version 9, behaves differently:

```
jd[{2012, 11, 24, 12}] - 2456256
0.
jd[{1100, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}] - 2123154
0.
jd[{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}] - 625660
365.

jd[{-4713, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
366
```

and

```
DateList[{-4713, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
{-4713, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0.}
DateList[{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}]
{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0.}
```

Comment: I can't test now, but just on a hunch: if you're on a Linux system, could you compare what happens if you use Unix time (e.g. via `Get["!date +%s"]`) to compute JD?

Comment: @J.M.: OS X: 1353817092.

Comment: Eek, `Get["!date +%s"]` just computes Unix time! What I wanted to say was that you could try reckoning the formula for JD based on Unix time, and then compare with the method using `AbsoluteTime[]` and the true JD.

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a bug. Similarly, `AbsoluteTime[{2009,01,01,0,0,0}]-AbsoluteTime[{2008,12,31,23,59,59}]` gives `1` instead of the correct `2`, assuming the standard UTC+Gregorian.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Yes, that's an [additional issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15063/37), with leap seconds.

Comment: @J.M.: I believe I'm POSIX compliant, but that's the extent of my understanding; that is, UNIX time: a duplicated first post-leap-second second, that always maps back to the first second of the following day, and is not counted in time differences. Essentially: UTC with *gaps* where leap seconds should be. But that doesn't account for the behavior I see (e.g. `AstronomicalData` skips leap seconds, but reports results as if there were no gap).

Comment: @J.M.: Updated with different behavior in 9.0. `DateList` does (did) indeed seem to have a bug (that's now fixed). I'm not sure what's going on with `AbsoluteTime`, but it's probably not the way to calculate JD.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: `AbsoluteTime[{2009, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[{2008, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59}]` [still gives `1`, in version 9.0, rather than 2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15063/37).

Comment: Wolfram support has confirmed that change of date by `DateList` was a bug in version 8. It remains to be seen why `AbsoluteTime` added a day in 8 and a year in 9.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Please post that as an answer

Comment: @Verbeia: Wolfram "support" *still* hasn't given me a straight answer about the rest of the question. I'm working on it.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ok! Keep us posted.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Can you give an answer to this yet? Whatever you got I think will be good.

Comment: @Anon: "Premier" "Support" is still dragging its feet. I don't think they know.

Comment: Still there in version 10.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In version 10, I think that much of the behavior is simply a difference between how the year 0 is handled [by astronomers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering) (and therefore the page you were getting Julian Dates from) and everybody else.

For example, take this calculation:

```
jd[{-3000, 11, 24, 12, 0, 0}] - 625660
```

I believe that you have actually pulled the wrong number from the website due to a year 0 issue.  Consider this:

```
(AbsoluteTime[{1, 1, 1, 12}] - AbsoluteTime[{-1, 1, 1, 12}])/86400
```

366

Note that Mathematica will return a result consistent with the Gregorian/Julian calendars where there is no year 0.  But, your link reports that the Julian Day of 1,1,1,12 is:

1721426

and the Julian day of -1,1,1,12 is:

1720695

a difference of 2 years.  This is consistent with how an astronomy specific app should work.  If you account for this difference in years, I believe that the results will be consistent (in Mathematica 10, past results were just incorrect, as noted in comments).