# Why doesn't RulePlot understand the TuringMachine in the documentation?

Tags: plotting, bugs, cellular-automata

The documentation for `TuringMachine` gives the following example of a machine specified by explicit transitions:

```
t = TuringMachine[
    {{state_,color_?EvenQ}:>{state,color/2,-1},{state_,color_?OddQ}:>{state,3 color+1,1}},
    {1,{1,2,3,4,5}},5];
```

But attempting to plot this with `RulePlot[t]` results in:

```
{{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 1, 
   0}, {4, 1, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 5, -1}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 1, 
   0}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 16}}, {{1, 5, -1}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 16}}}
```

Why doesn't `RulePlot` understand the explicit transitions `TuringMachine` in the documentation?

Comment: `ArrayPlot` works: `ArrayPlot[Last /@ t, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: But why doesn't `RulePlot`? I don't see anything in the "documentation" that suggests that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the following is not a solution, but an observation that grew too long for a comment. At first, I thought that the problem may be the fact that the initialization and number of steps should be given as arguments to `RulePlot` rather than to `TuringMachine`, so I tried:

```
Clear[separate]

separate := 
  RulePlot[
    TuringMachine[
      {{state_, color_?EvenQ} :> {state, color/2, -1},
       {state_, color_?OddQ} :> {state, 3 color + 1, 1}}
    ],
    {1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 5
  ]
```

... but that failed as well.

Reading through the results of `Trace@separate`, it appears to me that the following check returning `False` causes `RulePlot` to decide to fail and return unevaluated:

```
NKSSpecialFunctions`RulePlot`Dump`ValidTuringMachineRulesQ[{
   {state_, color_?EvenQ} :> {state, color/2, -1}, 
   {state_, color_?OddQ} :> {state, 3 color + 1, 1}
}]

(* Out: False *)
```

None of these checks appear when one executes `Trace@t` using your definition of the `TuringMachine`.

Comment: So what's happening here? Is this another failure of the documentation, or another bug?

Comment: The `TuringMachine` expression works, and `RulePlot` works with other forms of `TuringMachine` expressions, but not with this one, so I am leaning towards bug here. Unless somebody else comes up with a better explanation, I'd report it to WRI Support.

Comment: I'm weary of reporting bugs. Nearly every single thing I've ever tried as a simple experiment in Mathematica has uncovered a fundamental bug. I just got notification that one [I uncovered in 2012](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15063/37) was finally fixed — **8 years later**.