# Inaccurate Heliocentric coordinates of PlanetaryMoonData

Tags: curated-data, precision-and-accuracy, astronomy

I have noticed that the heliocentric coordinates obtained with [`PlanetaryMoonData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanetaryMoonData.html) are very inaccurate. Fore example, consider the Galilean moons of Jupiter:

```
gmJ = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "GalileanMoon"]];
{europaXYZ, kalistoXYZ, ganimedXYZ, ioXYZ} = 
  PlanetaryMoonData[#, 
     EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
      "HelioCoordinates", {"Date" -> 
        DateObject[3644683200 + (3600*2 + 60*1 + 14)]}]] & /@ gmJ;
```

Notice that all the coordinates are the same:

```
SameQ @@ {europaXYZ, kalistoXYZ, ganimedXYZ, ioXYZ}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

On further inspection, it seems to just return the heliocentric coordinates of their parent body, i.e. Jupiter:

```
jupiterXYZ = 
  PlanetData["Jupiter", 
   EntityProperty["Planet", 
    "HelioCoordinates", {"Date" -> 
      DateObject[3644683200 + (3600*2 + 60*1 + 14)]}]];

SameQ @@ {europaXYZ, kalistoXYZ, ganimedXYZ, ioXYZ, jupiterXYZ}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Using `SetPrecision` when evaluating the calls to `PlanetaryMoonData` seems to have no effect.
How to obtain better quality data of the moons' heliocentric coordinates?

Comment: I don't think the currated astronomical data has observatory accuracy (nor do I think it is it intended to). It appears to be kept as a machine float in AU. So trying to set precision won't have any effect. Further, on the scale of AUs, Jupiter and its Galilean moons are essential all in the same place.

Comment: You can always use Jupiter's heliocentric coordinates and add in the moons' Jupiter-centric (Jovian) coordinates, no?

Comment: @barrycarter I can't do that because Mathematica does not provide the true anomaly of the moons, which is needed to calculate their time-dependent orbital parameters. If you know a different way, let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for the orbital parameters or do you just need the position? Mathematica will give you the parameters and the position.

Comment: @barrycarter can you provide an example? I need heliocentric XYZ coordinates, but even time-dependent orbital parameters will help.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Still looking into this, but here's the latest reply from Wolfram:

> The Scientific Astronomer package you are referencing was a third
>   party package that the company never maintained. It looks as though it
>   has not been updated since version 5.
>
> You will find similar functionality in the interpreters listed under
>   Related Interpreters at the following link:
>
> http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/AstronomicalObjectClass.html
>
> I cannot say if the exact functionality from that package has been
>   implemented in more recent versions however, as we did not maintain
>   the package.

EDIT: It appears that Mathematica has or had a product 
called Scientific Astronomer that did this. Snapshotting 
pages 44-45 (pages 56-57 of the PDF version) of:

http://media.wolfram.com/documents/ScientificAstronomerDocumentation.pdf

[image]
[image]

Presumably, Wolfram won't give away for free what they sell 
in a separate software package.

The unusual thing here is that all the links I found to 
purchase Scientific Astronomer are either broken or lead to 
a generic "packages" pages. See also: 
[How do I determine astronomical transit times?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/) which 
mentions Scientific Astronomer is a "legacy" package.

You may also want to ping Wolfram. Searching for 
'"scientific astronomer" site:wolfram.com' (as quoted) 
yields several results, but no actual mention I could find 
of how to obtain the package.

ORIGINAL ANSWER: Too long for a comment, but not an answer.

OK, I think I see your problem now. When I did 
`AstronomicalData["Io", "Properties"]` (I'm using an older 
version of Mathematica), I did see `Position` as one of the 
values. However, Mathematica yields `Missing[Variable]` for 
Io's position (and it works for Jupiter and the Sun, so 
it's not because I'm not providing a date object). 
Apparently, `Properties` just returns a template that may 
or may not work in a specific case.

I did:

`t2=Table[{i,AstronomicalData["Io",i]},{i,AstronomicalData["Io","Properties"]}];`

and got:

```
 
In[13]:= t2 // TableForm

Out[13]//TableForm=

>   AbsoluteMagnitude        Missing[NotAvailable]

    AbsoluteMagnitudeH       Missing[NotAvailable]

    Albedo                   0.63

    AlphanumericName         Io

    AlternateNames           Jupiter I

    AlternateStandardNames   JupiterI

    Altitude                 Missing[Variable]

                                     8
    Apoapsis                 4.235 10

    ApparentMagnitude        Missing[Variable]

    AscendingNodeLongitude   43.977

    Azimuth                  Missing[Variable]

    Classes                  PlanetaryMoon

    Constellation            Missing[Variable]

    ConstellationName        Missing[Variable]

    Declination              Missing[Variable]

    Density                  3528.

                                      6
    Diameter                 3.6432 10

    DiscoveryYear            1610

    Distance                 Missing[Variable]

    DistanceLightYears       Missing[Variable]

    Eccentricity             0.0041

    EquatorialDiameter       Missing[NotAvailable]

    EquatorialRadius         Missing[NotAvailable]

    EscapeVelocity           2558.0

    Gravity                  1.7961

    Image                    -Image-

    Inclination              0.036

    LastRiseTime             Missing[Variable]

    LastSetTime              Missing[Variable]

                                      22
    Mass                     8.9298 10

    Name                     Io

    NextRiseTime             Missing[Variable]

    NextSetTime              Missing[Variable]

    ObjectType               PlanetaryMoon

    Oblateness               Missing[NotAvailable]

    Obliquity                0.

    OrbitCenter              Jupiter

                                     5
    OrbitPeriod              1.528 10

    OrbitPeriodYears         0.004843

                                                      8
                             SemimajorAxis -> 4.218 10
                             Eccentricity -> 0.0041
                             Inclination -> 0.036
                             PeriapsisArgument -> 84.129
                             AscendingNodeLongitude -> 43.977
                             PeriapsisLongitude -> Missing[NotAvailable]
                                                  8
                             Periapsis -> 4.201 10
                                                 8
    OrbitRules               Apoapsis -> 4.235 10

                                     8
    Periapsis                4.201 10

    PeriapsisArgument        84.129

    PeriapsisLongitude       Missing[NotAvailable]

    PolarDiameter            Missing[NotAvailable]

    PolarRadius              Missing[NotAvailable]

    Position                 Missing[Variable]

    PositionLightYears       Missing[Variable]

                                      6
    Radius                   1.8216 10

    RightAscension           Missing[Variable]

                                     5
    RotationPeriod           1.528 10

                                     8
    SemimajorAxis            4.218 10

    Speed                    Missing[Variable]

    StandardName             Io
```

Several options:

- It's possible this functionality is available in a 
  Mathematica add-on, but a lot of add-on functionality is 
  now part of Mathematica itself. However, you may want to 
  look at:

http://www.wolfram.com/products/fields/

just in case I missed something.

- If you just need a table of Io position data: 
  http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi
- If you're OK with using something other than 
  Mathematica to compute positions: 
  http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html
- There's also pyephem, skyfield, Astro::Nova and 
  doubtless many others, though the CSPICE libraries above 
  are the ones NASA uses.
- Finally, I've converted some position data to 
  Mathematica format. I can provide more details, but, 
  unless you absolutely have to use Mathematica, I wouldn't 
  recommend this method.

Comment: I think WRI actually does not care about preserving the novelty of these commercial add-on packages. They are third-party tools and only half-heartedly resold by WRI. More than once, the author of such a package has been hired by WRI, and the functionality incorporated into *Mathematica* (most notable example: Roman Maeder's `Parallel\`` package). It seems the same has happened to Terry Robb, author of  *Scientific Astronomer*. Apart from that, the package is nearly 20 years old now (the documentation says it's written for *Mathematica* 3 or 4), and almost certainly no longer available.

Comment: Robb has since left WRI and seems to have dropped off the radar.

Comment: You are correct. I've added Wolfram's reply.