# 3D orbits of moons around their respective planets

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, simulation, astronomy

I have seen a lot of solar system models (both animated and not), but I am trying to replicate the same thing with moons. Either just one planet and its lunar system or the our whole solar system with the respective moons. However the "OrbitPath" function does not seem to work with these.

I am able to get the OrbitCircumference and other data like that, but I am not sure how to implement this into a system. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Currently I have the following code to determine the circumference of the moons around their respective planets:

```
data = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "EarthMoon"], 
  "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"]; data2 = 
 PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "MarsMoon"], 
  "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"];
data3 = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "JupiterMoon"],
    "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"];
data4 = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "SaturnMoon"], 
   "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"];
data5 = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "UranusMoon"], 
   "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"];
data6 = PlanetaryMoonData[EntityClass["PlanetaryMoon", "NeptuneMoon"],
    "OrbitCircumference", "EntityAssociation"];
UnitConvert[{data, data2, data3, data4, data5, 
  data6}, "astronomical units"]
```

but I don't know how I would get something like this, but with moons rather than planets:

```
Graphics3D[PlanetData[PlanetData[], "OrbitPath"]]
```

I also tried this

```
Graphics3D[MinorPlanetData[MinorPlanetData["Mars"], "OrbitPath"]]
```

but all i got was errors and it took ages to run.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question? Please show your due diligence, share the code you are working on. Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) making it more specificly about Mathematica programming. Otherwise it may be closed.

Comment: `AstronomicalData["Moon", "Properties"]` for getting the properties of an object

Comment: You'll have to compute the ellipse yourself based on `AstronomicalData["Ganymede", "OrbitRules"]` or similar. Or you can use NASA's SPICE libraries and data if this is more than a casual query.

Comment: Thanks for the  helpful comments. @barrycarter once I have that data, how do I implement it into a working model?

Comment: I'm guessing you would use some combination of ParametricPlot3D and Animate? It would really depend on how you want the model to look.

Comment: There's a fair bit of interest in Jupiter's 4 largest moons, so I'm somewhat surprised no one has done this (at least for Jupiter + the 4 big moons) yet. BTW, feel free to contact me (see my profile) if you want help in real time, and you can post the results here.

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85235/inaccurate-heliocentric-coordinates-of-planetarymoondata (just making this comment to create the link)

Comment: @barrycarter You may be interested in my answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Please provide credit if you use (parts of) this code anywhere, I spent a lot of time on it.

The Ephemeris data comes from [The NASA HORIZONS Web-Interface](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), and has been generated for `00:00-1-1-2000`, with respect to the Barycenters of the Solar system, Jupiter System, and Saturn System, using the VECTORS Ephemeris type.

My answer here doesn't rely `PlanetaryMoonData[]`, the reason is that it is built around an all-purpose physical interaction system which I have also used for fictional physical systems.

Where possible I use AU units with Standard gravitational parameters instead of Mass, point is to be consistent. AU is more accurate than SI. For clarity's sake I'll put the actual init data in pastebin, please paste the result here into an input cell:

[LINK TO FIRST MMA CELL](http://pastebin.com/8PpfwbXe)

As J.M. pointed out, you can import this directly into *MMA* with

```
Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/8PpfwbXe", "Package"]
```

This is the actual engine: it is a function which inputs the data in the form of the pastebin file:
As you may want to generate a system for many different particles/ planets/ moons, there is a progress monitor:

```
generate[dataset_, rep_, nn_, {xxm_, yym_, zzm_}, mm_, tmax_] := 
 Module[{n, positions, velocities, m, xt, xz, yt, yz, zt, zz, xm, ym, 
   zm, rm, xf1, xf, yf1, yf, zf1, zf, pos, vel},
  (*Setting up basic data*)
  n = Length[dataset];
  nn = n;
  positions = Transpose[Table[dataset[[i, 2]], {i, n}]];
  velocities = Transpose[Table[dataset[[i, 3]], {i, n}]];
  m = Table[dataset[[i, 4]], {i, n}];
  mm = m;
  (*Setting up stuff for NDSolve[]*)
  {xt, yt, 
    zt} = {ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, n}]], 
    ToExpression[Table["y" <> ToString[i], {i, n}]], 
    ToExpression[Table["z" <> ToString[i], {i, n}]]};
  {xm, ym, zm} = {Through[xt[t]], Through[yt[t]], Through[zt[t]]};
  {xz, yz, zz} = {Through[xt[0]], Through[yt[0]], Through[zt[0]]};
  yt = ToExpression[Table["y" <> ToString[i], {i, n}]];
  zt = ToExpression[Table["z" <> ToString[i], {i, n}]];
  rm = Flatten[
     Table[If[i != j, 
       Sqrt[(xm[[j]] - xm[[i]])^2 + (ym[[j]] - ym[[i]])^2 + (zm[[j]] -
             zm[[i]])^2]], {i, n}, {j, n}]] /. Null -> Sequence[];
  (*The final equations for the differential equation*)

  xf1 = (Flatten[
       Table[If[i != j, (xm[[j]] - xm[[i]]) m[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, 
         n}]] /. Null -> Sequence[])/rm^3;
  xf = Thread[
    D[D[xm, t], t] == 
     Table[Total[Take[xf1, {(n - 1) i - n + 2, (n - 1) i}]], {i, 
       n}]];
  yf1 = (Flatten[
       Table[If[i != j, (ym[[j]] - ym[[i]]) m[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, 
         n}]] /. Null -> Sequence[])/rm^3;
  yf = Thread[
    D[D[ym, t], t] == 
     Table[Total[Take[yf1, {(n - 1) i - n + 2, (n - 1) i}]], {i, 
       n}]];
  zf1 = (Flatten[
       Table[If[i != j, (zm[[j]] - zm[[i]]) m[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, 
         n}]] /. Null -> Sequence[])/rm^3;
  {xxm, yym, zzm} = {xm, ym, zm};
  zf = Thread[
    D[D[zm, t], t] == 
     Table[Total[Take[zf1, {(n - 1) i - n + 2, (n - 1) i}]], {i, n}] ];
  pos = {Thread[xz == positions[[1]]], Thread[yz == positions[[2]]], 
    Thread[zz == positions[[3]]]};
  vel = {Thread[D[xm, t] == velocities[[1]]] /. t -> 0, 
    Thread[D[ym, t] == velocities[[2]]] /. t -> 0, 
    Thread[D[zm, t] == velocities[[3]]] /. t -> 0};
  Print["Now generating Interpolation functions for ", 
   dataset[[All, 1]], "..."];
  rep = Monitor[NDSolve[Flatten[{xf, yf, zf,
       vel, pos}], Flatten[{xt, yt, zt}], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], MaxStepSize -> 0.5, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], ProgressIndicator[time/tmax]];
  Print["Done."]]
```

Now we input the data. `dataSol` is the data generate of the pastebin cell, the solution gets stored in `s`, `n` stores the amount of particles, `{xm, ym, zm}` gets the `InterpolationFunctions[]`, `m` gets the relative masses, for plotting purposes, and you need to set `tmax` the time in days. In the first case `a` sets the amount of years the solar ystem is computed.

```
a = 256;
Clear[s, n, xm, ym, zm, m]
generate[dataSol, s, n, {xm, ym, zm}, m, 
 tmax1 = 365*a + Ceiling[a/4]]
Clear[s2, n2, xm2, ym2, zm2, m2]
generate[dataJupiter, s2, n2, {xm2, ym2, zm2}, m2, tmax2 = 20]
Clear[s3, n3, xm3, ym3, zm3, m3]
generate[dataSaturn, s3, n3, {xm3, ym3, zm3}, m3, tmax3 = 20]
```

This is an example of how to plot it:
Top-left: Solar System upto Ceres, top-right: Solar System starting at Jupiter.
Bottom-left: Jupiter system, bottom-right: Saturn system.

```
Grid[{{Manipulate[
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[
       Flatten[Thread[Transpose[{xm, ym, zm}][[1 ;; 7]] /. s], 
        1]], {t, t0, a}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-0.75, 0.75}}, 
      PlotStyle -> ps[[1 ;; 7]], Background -> Black, 
      ImageSize -> Large], 
     Graphics3D[
      Transpose[{colours[[1 ;; 7]], 
        Thread[Sphere[
          Evaluate[
           Flatten[
            Thread[Transpose[{xm, ym, zm} /. t -> a][[1 ;; 7]] /. s], 
            1]], sizes1a[[1 ;; 7]]]]}]]], {t0, 0, Min[tmax1, 700] - 1,
      1}, {{a, Min[tmax1, 700], "t"}, t0 + 1, Min[tmax1, 700], 1}], 
   Manipulate[
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[
       Flatten[Thread[
         Transpose[{xm, ym, zm}][[{1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]] /. s], 
        1]], {t, t0, a}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-45, 45}, {-45, 45}, {-10, 10}}, 
      PlotStyle -> ps[[{1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]], Background -> Black, 
      ImageSize -> Large], 
     Graphics3D[
      Transpose[{colours[[{1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]], 
        Thread[Sphere[
          Evaluate[
           Flatten[
            Thread[Transpose[{xm, ym, zm} /. t -> a][[{1, 8, 9, 10, 
                11, 12}]] /. s], 1]], 
          sizes1b[[{1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]]]]}]]], {t0, 0, tmax1 - 1, 
     1}, {{a, tmax1, "t"}, t0 + 1, tmax1, 1}]}, {Manipulate[
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[
       Flatten[Thread[Transpose[{xm2, ym2, zm2}] /. s2], 1]], {t, t0, 
       a}, PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.005, 
         0.005}}, PlotStyle -> ps2, Background -> Black, 
      ImageSize -> Large], 
     Graphics3D[
      Transpose[{colours2, 
        Thread[Sphere[
          Evaluate[
           Flatten[Thread[Transpose[{xm2, ym2, zm2} /. t -> a] /. s2],
             1]], sizes2]]}]]], {t0, 0, tmax2 - 1, 
     1}, {{a, tmax2, "t"}, t0 + 1, tmax2, 1}], 
   Manipulate[
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[
       Flatten[Thread[Transpose[{xm3, ym3, zm3}] /. s3], 1]], {t, t0, 
       a}, PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.005, 
         0.005}}, PlotStyle -> ps3, Background -> Black, 
      ImageSize -> Large], 
     Graphics3D[
      Transpose[{colours3, 
        Thread[Sphere[
          Evaluate[
           Flatten[Thread[Transpose[{xm3, ym3, zm3} /. t -> a] /. s3],
             1]], sizes3]]}]]], {t0, 0, tmax3 - 1, 
     1}, {{a, tmax3, "t"}, t0 + 1, tmax3, 1}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Where do the numbers in `dataSol`, `dataJupiter`, etc. come from?

Comment: @shrx Good point, I've added that to the top of the answer.

Comment: If you want to load the data without needing to copy-pasta: `Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/8PpfwbXe", "Package"]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, I've added that to the answer.